# How to read the status from a response in python when a call to an api is made

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using urllib3 in python like this

```
        urllib3.disable_warnings()
        https = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

I am calling an api like this

```
        a = {"name": joy.txt, "parent":{"id": 4567}}
           resp = https.request(method='POST',    
            url = https://zoola.com/content, 
            headers=headers,  
            fields = {
              "attributes": json.dumps(a),
              "file": (joy.txt, file),
              "filename": joy.txt
            }
        )
```

I am getting my response like this

```
    myresponse = resp.data.decode('UTF-8')
```

I need to be able to test a status of the response like this

```
    if resp.status == "201":
        #Do something
```

This gives me an internal server error. How can I read the status? resp does not have a status property

Comment: What is the exact error? Could you produce a Minimal Reproducible Example? HTTPResponse should have the `status` attribute according to the doc: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html#response-content. But the type of status is int, not string.

Comment: It is going to be tough to reproduce this example. The error I got was "internal server error" . It didn't like the if resp.status == "201". I will remove the quotes around 201 and try again